Why do the coordinates of the origin of the line not change when moving the object?
I am programming Revit API 2024 on the C# and WPF platform. I am having an issue.

"The coordinates of the line's start and end points do not change when I move the object, leading to the tool scattering the rebar outside the object when applied."




Hi there! See here for how to ask a good question on StackOverflow.  Please look at how to create a minimum reproducible example.
